# Vue Website give 404 error when i try to access with website.com/pagename

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, netlify

I am learning vue and firebase.I just deployed my app on netlify server after `build`.All ok but i try to directly access my site with page name like this is my app [To Vue](https://vuefire-auth.netlify.app/).It have 5 pages `signin`, `signup`, `home`, `global`, `profile` and `404`. My app open and work correctly when i open home like like `https://vuefire-auth.netlify.app` but i try to open with page name like `https://vuefire-auth.netlify.app/signup` netlify give me error.How to handle it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `_redirects` file in your project with the following content:

```
/*   /index.html   200
```

This rule ensures that every path successfully resolves to index.html and the client has full control over the routing logic.

Read article: [Creating better, more predictable redirect rules for SPAs](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/07/creating-better-more-predictable-redirect-rules-for-spas/)